# WPF ApplicationData throw System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a WPF project that has a Startup UWP project.
My library stopped working correctly for only one application. I found a place where she was throwing exceptions

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

[image]

I wanted to see what is inside ApplicationData, and this is what I found:

[image]

Unfortunately I was not able to create a minimal application to reproduce this error. How do I solve the Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder exception?

Comment: You explained almost nothing about your library.

Comment: It uses the local location of the program to save some data there. But this no matter because i have other problem